# Pandas / SQLITE DataFrame plot

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas, dataframe

I try to plot data from sqlite but i can't achieve this :-/

```
p2 = sql.read_sql('select DT_COMPUTE_FORCAST,VALUE_DEMANDE,VALUE_FORCAST from PCE', cnx)

# Data frame p2 show the datas
      DT_COMPUTE_FORCAST  VALUE_DEMANDE  VALUE_FORCAST
0       27/06/2014 06:00          5.128          5.324
1       27/06/2014 07:00          5.779          5.334
2       27/06/2014 08:00          5.539          5.354

df = pd.DataFrame({'Demande' : p2['VALUE_DEMANDE'],'Forcast' :p2['VALUE_FORCAST']},index=p2['DT_COMPUTE_FORCAST'])

df.plot(title='Title Here')
```

=> My chart is showing but with no values, could you give me a hint ?!

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 20109 entries, 27/06/2014 06:00 to 11/05/2015 05:00
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Demande    0 non-null float64
Forcast    0 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 392.8+ KB
```

the followinf sentence is the correct or i miss something ?:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Demande' : p2['VALUE_DEMANDE'],'Forcast' : p2['VALUE_FORCAST']},index=p2['DT_COMPUTE_FORCAST'])
```

Comment: can you post the output from `df.info()`

Comment: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 20109 entries, 27/06/2014 06:00 to 11/05/2015 05:00
Data columns (total 2 columns):
Demande    0 non-null float64
Forcast    0 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 392.8+ KB

Comment: Please edit the output into your question, not as a comment. The formatting is lost

Comment: Well the answer is there, you have 0 data values

Comment: Can you try `df = pd.DataFrame({'Demande' : p2['VALUE_DEMANDE'],'Forcast' :p2['VALUE_FORCAST']})` first and then assign to the index after df construction: `df.index = p2['DT_COMPUTE_FORCAST']`

Comment: you rocks EdChum thank you very much...  ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure why specifically passing the index should fail other than you're passing the columns from whatever `p2` is and then the alignment fails because your index values are not present in the data you're passing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what happens here is that because you pass the data from `p2` and using one of the columns as the index, the index values no longer align so you end up with 0 values. You can get around this by assigning the index after the df creation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Demande' : p2['VALUE_DEMANDE'],'Forcast' :p2['VALUE_FORCAST']})
```

and then

```
df.index = p2['DT_COMPUTE_FORCAST']
```

Example:

```
In [160]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(5), 'b':list('abcde')})
df
Out[160]:
   a  b
0  0  a
1  1  b
2  2  c
3  3  d
4  4  e
In [161]:

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a_copy':df['a']}, index=df['b'])
df1
Out[161]:
   a_copy
b        
a     NaN
b     NaN
c     NaN
d     NaN
e     NaN
```

Another way to get around this is to access the `.values` attribute so that the data is anonymous:

```
In [162]:

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a_copy':df['a'].values}, index=df['b'])
df1
Out[162]:
   a_copy
b        
a       0
b       1
c       2
d       3
e       4
```

So the following should work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Demande' : p2['VALUE_DEMANDE'].values,'Forcast' : p2['VALUE_FORCAST'].values},index=p2['DT_COMPUTE_FORCAST'])
```

Comment: @EdChum indeed, in the DataFrame constructor, if providing values as a series/dataframe and specifying an index, it does a reindexing operation. However, in this case, I think the easier solution is just to rename the original dataframe and setting the index.